# HTML Table with 5 rows and 5 columns

Tags: html

How do I create an HTML table with 5 rows and 5 columns?

I tried the following arrangement

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I only get 5 columns and 3 rows. Please help

Thanks, is there an easier way than just writing 5 lines each?

Comment: You could use Javascript and a for-loop to create n-columns / rows.

Comment: This question is not off-topic! as Simo pointed out, the answer is to use Javascript. The asker may not have been aware of it. This is not a small issue anymore: https://www.facebook.com/ProgrammersCreateLife/photos/a.241809332534619.55240.241806149201604/1708082789240592/?type=3

Comment: @DavidI.Samudio : I am sorry, but I fail to see your point. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Hi @Yuriko, the reason why this question was closed is inconsequential: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error...". The underlying problem was the asker only knowing HTML and intuitively was looking for a programmatic approach, in this case, JS, but he/she was not aware of it.  Perhaps, the question was confused with trolling, but no discussion was given, nor the benefit of the doubt prevailed. It shows that the tolerance to questions from beginners is really low.

Comment: Interestingly, it got plenty of traction on Facebook, where plenty of users reacted to this question and critiqued the lack of support from the community to newcomers.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR: You only provided 3 `<tr>` markups, so you only got 3 rows.**

In HTML, tables have the following basic structure<sup>1</sup>:

```
table
|- row_1
|  |- data_1
|  `- data_2
|- row_2
|  |- ...
...
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> - Other markups exist such as `th`, `thead`, etc. but for clarity's sake I'm ignoring them. [More info here. (MDN Table element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)</sup>

You first declare the table with the `<table>` markup, and then the rows with the `<tr>` markup. (**t**able **r**ow.)
Inside each row, you can declare the data containers `<td>`. (**t**able **d**ata).

Here's a snippet of HTML code to create a table with 5 columns and 5 rows:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;

}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row_1/col_1</td>
    <td>col_2</td>
    <td>col_3</td>
    <td>col_4</td>
    <td>col_5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row_2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row_3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row_4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row_5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<tr>` is short for table row. You only have 3, so you'll only get 3 rows and not 5. Add 2 more rows.

Edit: Added some javascript.

```js
let table = document.getElementById("table");

//fake data
const contentList = [
   //row1
   [{title: "title"},{title: "title"},{title: "title"}],
   //row2
   [{title: "title"},{title: "title"},{title: "title"}],
   //row3
   [{title: "title"},{title: "title"},{title: "title"}]
];

//function to generate a row.
const rowTemplate = (data, rowNumber) =>{
    let rowString = "<tr>";
    data.forEach((td, index)=>{
        rowString += `<td>${td.title}, row: ${rowNumber}, column: ${index}</td>`;
    });
    rowString += "</tr>"
    return rowString;
};

//function to generate all the rows
const generateRows = (data, elementToPopulate) => {
    let htmlString = "";
    data.forEach((row,index)=>{
        htmlString += rowTemplate(row, index);
    });
    elementToPopulate.innerHTML = htmlString;
}

//call method
generateRows(contentList, table);
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" id="table">
</table>
```

Comment: Is this looks to be part of the answer, why is it off-topic? This and a JS loop(Asimo comment) helps new web developers to understand how to program when they find some kind of barrier.